# Factor column 1 and transpose the corresponding rows of other columns according to factored levels of column 1

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, transpose

I have a large data frame, directly imported from SQL database with the following type of structure (for reproducible example):

[image: Data structure]

I want to factor first 3 columns, ‘id’, ‘day’ and ‘type’. These 3 columns are  always dependent on each other and factorise accordingly. 
For the factored columns I want to transpose column ‘valueTitle’ into rows to be the new column titles and transpose column ‘value’ into rows under correct ‘valueTitle’. It should look as this:

[image: Desired output]

Reproducible example:

```
id <- c(5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7) 
day <- c("01.01.2000", "01.01.2000", "01.01.2000", "01.01.2001", "01.01.2001", "01.01.2001", "01.01.2002", "01.01.2002", "01.01.2002") 
type <- c("green", "green", "green","orange","orange","orange", "blue", "blue", "blue")
valueTitle <- c("title1","title2","title3","title1","title2","title3","title1","title2","title3")
value <- c(0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 0.6, 0.9, 0.9, 2, 1, 7)
df <- data.frame(id, day, type, valueTitle, value) 
df$id<-as.factor(df$id)      
df

  id        day   type valueTitle value
1  5 01.01.2000  green     title1   0.2
2  5 01.01.2000  green     title2   0.6
3  5 01.01.2000  green     title3   0.9
4  6 01.01.2001 orange     title1   0.6
5  6 01.01.2001 orange     title2   0.9
6  6 01.01.2001 orange     title3   0.9
7  7 01.01.2002   blue     title1   2.0
8  7 01.01.2002   blue     title2   1.0
9  7 01.01.2002   blue     title3   7.0
```

I was looking for a solution using only vectorised operations but thought long about it and couldn't find a good way. I came up only with the following solution but based on a loop, which seems wrong for many reasons:

```
m<-matrix(ncol=3,nrow=3); m<-as.data.frame(m);m # pretend I know the real size, in reality this is not fixed
for ( i in  min(levels(df$id)):max(levels(df$id))){ 
  m[(df$id==i), ]<-(df[ ,('value')])
}
m<-t(m)
df2<-data.frame(m)
colnames(df2)<-(levels(df$valueTitle))
df2 <- cbind(id=levels(df$id), df2[,1:ncol(df2)])
df2

   id        day   type title1 title2 title3
V1  5 01.01.2000   blue    0.2    0.6    0.9
V2  6 01.01.2001  green    0.6    0.9    0.9
V3  7 01.01.2002 orange    2.0    1.0    7.0
```

Which is wrong because 'type' is mixed up, and either way, this method leads to many potential errors.  My real data set is large and number of 'valueTitle' can vary for different 'id'.

Can you suggest any method that would more efficiently carry out the factor and transpose operations on such data?

(If there is a method to do this directly in SQL it would be nice too!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, id+day+type~valueTitle, value.var='value')
```

Or `spread` from `tidyr` to reshape from 'long' format to 'wide'.

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df, valueTitle, value)
```

Comment: Thanks! dcast() works after some additional work, I had to create new table with integer index corresponding to each 'valueTitle' because there were duplicates in 'valueTitle' and apparently dcast() has problems with handling non-unique arguments. I will post the solution soon.

Comment: @DianaLog  In that case, we need to create a sequence column by the grouping 'valueTitle' and then use `dcast`

Answer (score 1):

Using `PIVOT`:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab (
   id         INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,[day]       DATE  NOT NULL
  ,type       VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL
  ,valueTitle VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
  ,value      NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #tab (id,[day],type,valueTitle,value) 
VALUES (5,'2000-01-01','green','title1',0.2), (5,'2000-01-01','green','title2',0.6),
(5,'2000-01-01','green','title3',0.9), (6,'2001-01-01','orange','title1',0.6),
(6,'2001-01-01','orange','title2',0.9),(6,'2001-01-01','orange','title3',0.9),
(7,'2002-01-01','blue','title1',2.0), (7,'2002-01-01','blue','title2',1.0),
(7,'2002-01-01','blue','title3',7.0);

SELECT id, [day], type,title1, title2, title3
FROM #tab
PIVOT (MAX(value)
       FOR valueTitle IN (title1, title2, title3)) p;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379195)**</kbd>